# Only first letter is printing using return statement in function

Tags: python

I want to print each letter of fruit in separate line using python.But only first letter is printing with return statement? Please help

```
def backword(fruit):
    index = 0
    while index < len(fruit):
       letter = fruit[index]
       return (letter)
       
       index = index + 1

print(backword('banana'))
```

Output :

```
b
```

I want to print each letter of fruit in separate line using python

Comment: You are confusing `print` and `return`, read your tutorials / class notes again. Everything (`index = index + 1` here) after a `return` statement won't be executed.

Comment: Also, when you use return in a loop, that'll stop the loop (and outer function) immediately

Comment: By the way, `return fruit[::-1]` would be the Python way to reverse a string

Comment: yes i know that code stops executing after return statement.is there anyway that i print entire string 'banana' using return statement?

Comment: You need to save the elements you extract to a data structure and return the data structure after all the elements have been saved.

Comment: @farhanhubble Can you please help me in my code how can i return the elements in data structor ?

Comment: Create a list. Append each element to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try using print instead of return on the while loop

```py
def backward(fruit):
    index = 0
    while index < len(fruit):
        letter = fruit[index]
        print(letter)
        index = index + 1

backward('banana')
```

Comment: While it solves one problem, this wouldn't print backward